# PySide6 or PyQt6 signal when local date changed

Tags: pyqt, pyside, pyside6, pyqt6

I'm writing a task monitor, where people can record the amount of time spent on each task per day. However, when the date changes, the records should be saved and generates new records of tasks for a new day with the amount of time 0.
Is there a good way to detect when the local date changed?
Thank you very much!

I assume using a QTimer is not the best way since I only need to check the date change at 12 AM (Maybe I can calculate the difference between 12 AM and the time that the user opens the program and put it into QTimer, but I'm wondering if there's any better way).

Comment: What does "better way" mean? What *specifically* is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: What makes you think that QTimer is not a valid choice? What you're proposing is actually a perfectly valid way to do it (and probably the most natural and reliable one when using only Qt). Just ensure that you're using a `PreciseTimer` type.

Comment: Thank you, I thought there was some signal that could be used as an alarm clock. I will go with my current solution with PreciseTimer.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante! That's helpful, I was calculating the interval manually and didn't know this function.

Comment: @angushushu Sorry, my previous comment was imprecise, I'm rewriting it, please wait a couple of minutes.

Comment: @angushushu Just remember that you properly check the remaining time using [`QDateTime.msecsTo()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#msecsTo). This is extremely important if the program is run in an area using Daylight Saving Time, and you may end up with the wrong interval: you may get a timeout off by an hour (or less in some zones) before or after the actual midnight, or even a wrongly set interval when the clock is pushed back: for instance, in my country we change time from 3AM to 2AM on the last Sunday of October, meaning that we get the hour from 2 to 3 *twice* that day.

Comment: @angushushu In that example, `now.msecsTo(nextDay)` will return the remaining time *after* the time adjustment for any given `now` that is between 2AM and the last millisecond before 3AM: if the program is run *before* that you'll get the timeout one hour earlier. I know this might be a fringe case, but it must never be underestimated, especially if you're keeping track of elapsed time. This also means that you need to be careful about this aspect in your program too, otherwise you'll end up with wrong values for task timing in case the program is used by people who may work at night.

Comment: @angushushu So, you cannot rely on basic QTime objects, but you must always use QDateTimes. You must also check *both* of them at least when you start up the program (or in case the timer has to be restarted for any reason) and verify if *both* of them use the same Daylight Time reference (see [`isDaylightTime()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdatetime.html)), and eventually compute the remaining/elapsed time accordingly. Note that, in order to get *actual* elapsed time, you should use [`QElapsedTimer`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html), which is (theoretically) granted to always be *monotonic*.